# asp-for does not generate code on Razor Page

Tags: razor-pages

I must be missing a configuration setting.
Simple example:

```
<input asp-for="Login.UserIDMaybe" type="text" class="inputStandard" placeholder="User ID" autofocus>
```

When the page compiles, the result is that exact same HTML, and when the form is submitted, the UserIDMaybe property of the model is always null.

To test that everything else is cool, I can replace that input HTML with the following, and it works (the Login.UserIDMaybe value is filled with what the user entered into the Input).

```
<input for="Login.UserIDMaybe" type="text" class="inputStandard" placeholder="User ID" autofocus>
```

Maybe I have completely misunderstood the usage of asp-for, or maybe I have failed to "turn it on". Thanks.

And yes "@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers" is in the _ViewImports.cshtml file, but maybe that is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC and Razor Pages, make sure you have a _ViewImports.cshtml in your Pages folder too.